# Linq joining same table with 4 different foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, foreign-keys

So I got my address table and my contract table. I want to loop through all the contracts and generate some Dtos out of them, but with the address-name & number instead of the id(guid). 
My problem is that there are 4 foreign keys on the addresstable from the contract table. Can I still do this with a join somehow, or maybe even multiple ones?

This is what Im trying at the moment:

```
  var contracts = context.Contracts
    .Join(context.Addresses, 
       (con => con.AddressId), 
       (adr => adr.AddressId), 
       (con,adr) 
       => new { contractInfo = con, addressInfo = adr });

      foreach(var a in contracts) {
          new MyDto() {
            AddressId = a.addressInfo.AddressNumber,
            AddressName = a.addressInfo.FullName,
            Date= a.contractInfo.Date,
            AnotherDate = a.contractInfo.AnotherDate,
            Text = a.contractInfo.Text,
            VerweisAdrId = a.addressInfo. // ???
            VerweisAdrName = a.addressInfo. // 2 more cases like this would follow
          }
        }
```

My other approach would probably generate way too many queries:

```
  var addresses = context.Addresses;
  var contracts = context.Contracts;

  foreach(var a in contracts) {
      new MyDto() {
        AddressId = addresses.Where(x => a.AddressId == x.AddressId).Select(y => y.AddressNumber);
        AddressName = addresses.Where(x => a.AddressId == x.AddressId).Select(y => y.FullName);
        Date= a.Date,
        AnotherDate = a.AnotherDate,
        Text = a.Text,
        VerweisAdrId = addresses.Where(x => a.VerweisAdrId == x.AddressId).Select(y => y.AddressNumber);
        VerweisAdrName = addresses.Where(x => a.VerweisAdrId == x.AddressId).Select(y => y.FullName);
      }
  }
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: You context should then have four tables.  Contracts is one table there should be more tables.

Comment: As in SQL, you can chain multiple `join`s. (BTW, in your second example, saying `a in contracts` is very confusing when you have `Addresses` running around - why didn't you say `c in contracts` and in the lambdas say `a => `...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var contracts = context.Contracts
    .Join(context.Addresses, 
       (con => con.AddressId), 
       (adr => adr.AddressId), 
       (con,adr) 
       => new { contractInfo = con, addressInfo = adr })
    .Join(context.Addresses,
        ca => ca.contractInfo.VerweisAdrId,
        adr => adr.AddressId,
        (ca, adr) => new { ca.contractInfo, ca.addressInfo, verweisAdr = adr })
    // ... and so on
    .Select(cavwx => new MyDto() {
        AddressId = cavwx.addressInfo.AddressNumber,
        AddressName = cavwx.addressInfo.FullName,
        VerweisAdrId = cavwx.verweisAdr.AddressNumber,
        VerweisAdrName = cavwx.verweisAdr.FullName,
        // ... and so on
     });
```